# Как тут правильно сформулировать регулярное выражение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть код:

```
result = re.search(r''+name+'\|\d\|',users)
```

Но есть проблема. Вылазит ошибка, что на исходе мы получаем обьект. Но ведь если убрать и сделать так:

```
result = re.search(r''+name+'\|\d',users)
```

То все работает, но гребет только первую цыфру. Почему?
Как правильно сделать?

Сама строка выглядит вот так:

```
1|username|100|
```

Answer (score 0):

Я просто не правильно сформулировал регулярку. Верно будет так:

```
result = re.search(r''+name+'\|[0-9]+\|',users)
```

Comment: `\d+` надо просто